# Разрыв страницы в Latex

Tags: вёрстка, latex, tex

Оформляю документ в TexStudio.
Получается у меня после раздела с заголовком \subsection{...} следует раздел с заголовком \section{Заключение},
между ними я указываю \newpage, но при этом раздел "Заключение" все равно на одной странице с предыдущим. Так же в \subsection{...} у меня присутствует таблица. Подскажите, это из-за того, что заголовки разных уровней или в чем то другом проблема?

Comment: Команду \clearpage пробовали?

Comment: Да, но тогда начинается пляска выше, рисунок и таблица съезжают. Рисунки и таблица закреплены - h.

Comment: В чем проблема - не ясно. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Может быть можно привести кусок кода с картинками как получается и с объяснением - чего хочется. Как-то не верится, чтобы такая команда как `\newpage` не справилась с созданием новой страницы в заданном месте.

Comment: Могу только посоветовать попробовать [h!] - хотя, кто-то из авторов очень не рекомендовал так делать. А вообще, товарищ выше прав - нужен минимальный рабочий кусок кода, чтобы можно было проверить на практике и понять, в чём дело.